# Console App Host ASPX Page?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis, console-application

In Framework 4.0 I have a little console app. I have a self-contained .aspx page (no codebehind) and would like to run the console app just to host this page. I searched around for tricks with System.ServiceModel.Web or System.Web.Services trying to find a way to do this.

Can anyone help me get clue?

Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by host? like IIS or you want to display it?

Comment: Have you tried if the solution works for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you seen [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/sv-se/magazine/cc163879%28en-us%29.aspx) article? It's not written for asp.net 4.0, it's written for asp.net 2.0, but I don't think there's much difference.

Comment: It basically works, basically. There seems to be no Close() method although it is in the source, I had to comment it out so the build works. But I get the idea. Thanks!

Comment: Link points to a paywall now, although you can get it at archive.org : https://web.archive.org/web/20130303021534/http://msdn.microsoft.com/sv-se/magazine/cc163879(en-us).aspx

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to host ASP.NET on a simple web server is to use the Cassini web server, which you can download from MS, including source code. The following two links help:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassini_Web_Server
- http://www.asp.net/downloads/archived-v11/cassini

After downloading, the only things you need to do are:

1. Comment out lines 92 through 96 of request.cs such that Cassini does not discard 
   requests coming from hosts other than localhost.
2. Run build, which builds and installs the Cassini library into the GAC.
3. Run the server.

**Note**: Cassini *is* a Console app, which just happens to show a form. If you're interested in it working purely as a Console app, refactor and remove the form. It should not be hard.

Comment: Cassini is a bit old, isn't it?